# Mybatis problem - convey parameter to my TypeHandler class through MyObjectFactory

Tags: java, mybatis

I have class TypeHandler that works normal.  But now i need to convey parametr - DB schema inside TypeHandler. I dont need to use this DB schema parametr as result, so i dont map it in mybatis-config.xml

Schema parametr used in  CallableStatement in ClobTypeHandler.

```
    public class ClobTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<String> {
        public String scheme;
    
        public ClobTypeHandler(String scheme) {
            this.scheme = scheme;
        }
    
        public ClobTypeHandler() {
        }
```

I've created my object factory:

```
public class ComponentObjectFactory extends DefaultObjectFactory {
                 String scheme;

                 public ComponentObjectFactory() {
                 }

                 public void setScheme(String scheme) {
                     this.scheme = scheme;
                 }

                 public <T> T create(Class<T> type) {
                     System.out.println("create:" + type);
                     return super.create(type);
                 }

                 public <T> T create(Class<T> type, List<Class<?>> constructorArgTypes, List<Object> constructorArgs) {
                     if (type.equals(ClobTypeHandler.class)) {
                         String scheme = (String)constructorArgs.get(0);
                         ClobTypeHandler cth = (ClobTypeHandler)super.create(type, constructorArgTypes, constructorArgs);
                         cth.scheme = scheme;
                         return cth;
                     } else {
                         return super.create(type, constructorArgTypes, constructorArgs);
                     }
                 }
             }
```

And registered it in mybatis-config:

```
<typeHandlers>
        <typeHandler javaType="java.lang.String"
                     jdbcType="CLOB"
                     handler="model.DB.ClobTypeHandler"/>
</typeHandlers>

<objectFactory type="services.ComponentObjectFactory">
    <property name="name" value="ComponentObjectFactory"/>
</objectFactory>
```

But when myBatis creates an instance of ClobTypeHandler - it not uses my ComponentObjectFactory and even  don't come to DefaultObjectFactory. I set breakpoints in constructors  there and see it. As result when debug comes to ClobTypeHandler - it s another instance, not my, that i created as

```
  ComponentObjectFactory cof = new ComponentObjectFactory();
cof.create(ClobTypeHandler.class, Arrays.asList(String.class), Arrays.asList(this.scheme));
```

1. How to force myBatis use my instance of ClobTypeHandler ?
2. How to force myBatis use my ComponentObjectFactory ?
3. How to force myBatis use only parameter constructor to convey schema parametr there ?

Comment: ObjectFactory is not used when instantiating type handlers. It looks weird that you need a string in a type handler. Could you explain how `scheme` is used in the `ClobTypeHandler` and why?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer.  It's very pity, i can't use ObjectFactory. Scheme is used in in such code(it not works without scheme):  private Clob createEmptyClob(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        CallableStatement cst = connection.prepareCall("{ call begin ? := " + this.scheme + "C_PKG_CLOB.fIns(); end }");```

Comment: I tried to convey schema via Connection (it would be ideal), but have java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException in   methods : Connection().getSchema() Connection().setSchema(scheme)
Connection().setClientInfo(props); (

Comment: It seems like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) situation i.e. your current approach (executing `call` statement in a type handler) may not be the right solution in the first place. If you explain the details about your initial requirement, we might be able to propose a better solution.

Comment: Maybe it's XY problem, i ask in borders of my view.  But i can not describe details. It's big enterprise application and now i dont know what exactly this call statement is doing.  I try ask my teamlead if we can remove call statement from handler.  Thanks again for your help.